# Memory allocation with a pattern known in advance

Tags: c++, memory-management, optimization, pattern-matching

I have an application where the sequence of malloc/free operations is known in advance. I'd like to do a pre-computation to minimize the maximum memory usage. Are there any resources on that (c++ implementations/research papers)?

More precisely, the same sequence of malloc/free operations is repeated many times (in the end of each cycle everything is freed). So I can afford some computation to optimize memory usage.

Comment: I think you'd need to specify the programming language being used too.

Comment: I am not aware of papers on this, but ` the same sequence of malloc/free operations is repeated many times (in the end of each cycle everything is freed)` sounds like you could create private heaps of specific size, allocate on them and then release the whole heap. Which platform do you use?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to be platform-independent (e.g. both windows and unix). Out of curiosity, on which platforms would this solution be possible? Could you give pointers to implementations of private heaps that allow this functionality?

Comment: With Windows, you have `HeapCreate`/`HeapFree`, which lets you deallocate the whole pile at once.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you want to achieve is minimize time spent allocating memory and possibly improve cache locality, this sounds quite simple, actually.

Just choose memory manager (write one or use a pre-existing such as Hoard). Then, let the memory manager allocate the maximum amount of memory used during a cycle at the start of the program.

The main issue is calculating this amount of memory. A simple solution would be to go through one cycle using an allocator which does nothing other than wrap malloc/free together with a counter which keeps track of current memory usage and maximum usage. At the end of your cycle, that maximum is how much you should allocate in the beginning.

The one thing to look out for is that fragmentation in your allocated memory could cause the need for extra allocations. This can usually be avoided by a good memory manager. In the worst case, you may have to track max memory allocated for every allocation size separately.

As a sidenote, if you are using C++, why are you using malloc/free instead of new/delete?

Answer (score 0):

> More precisely, the same sequence of malloc/free operations is
>   repeated many times (in the end of each cycle everything is freed). So
>   I can afford some computation to optimize memory usage.

For memory usage, this is not a hard case to solve. The same memory will be reallocated for the same purpose, so it's not "wasteful" of memory if you allocate the same lumps of memory over and over again.

Since you are saying, `malloc` and `free`, are we talking old style "C" type usage of the heap? So there's no constructors or destructors to worry about? Why not then create arrays of elements of a given type, e.g.

```
   struct X
   {
      ...
   };
```

Old code:

```
   X* px[10];
   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      px[i] = malloc(sizeof(X));
      ...
   }
```

instead do:

```
   X* px[10];
   X* xx = malloc(sizeof(X)*10);
   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      px[i] = &xx[i];
   }
```